# First letter input in EditText is not fully visible when using a custom font in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I can't seem to make my first letters show correctly when using a custom font with EditText in Android Studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:fontFamily="@font/telly_humble"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:text="jay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: example]

Edit: forgot to mention that I also tried padding-left or start, neither worked for me.

My final solution would be to change the font.

Comment: try after removing marginLeft.

Comment: put paddingleft and check it.

Comment: I have tried padding before that's why I tried also marginLeft instead of paddingLeft none of them worked well.

Comment: It isn't the best solution, but you can simply add a whitespace before the text

Comment: Can you please add you custom font xml file as well ?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I don't use a custom font XML file.

Comment: So your font file, don't you have one?

Comment: I do have it, but I am not going to put an external link here, you can google either telly_humble font or white_chunti

Answer (score 0):

Try to add paddingLeft.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:fontFamily="@font/telly_humble"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:text="jay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I already tried the padding but still no good.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding on the left and Right side it should solve the issue

```
<EditText
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:fontFamily="@font/telly_humble"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:text="jay" />
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I already tried the padding but still no good.

Comment: I think the custom font family doesn't have much safe area. was this issue fixed ?

Comment: or try https://material.io/components/text-fields/android